# web scraping issue with HTML class

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.digikey.com/products/en/inductors-coils- 
chokes/fixed-inductors/71/page/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

part_numbers = df["Manufacturer Part Number"].tolist()
manufacturer = df["Manufacturer"].tolist()
quantity_available = df["Quantity Available"].tolist()
m_qty = df["Minimum Quantity"].tolist()
types = df["Type"].tolist()
material = df["Material - Core"].tolist()
inductance = df["Inductance"].tolist()
tolerance = df["Tolerance"].tolist()
current_rating = df["Current Rating"].tolist()
current_saturation = df["Current - Saturation"].tolist()
shielding = df["Shielding"].tolist()
resistances = df["DC Resistance (DCR)"].tolist()
freq = df["Q @ Freq"].tolist()
frequency = df["Frequency - Self Resonant"].tolist()
ratings = df["Ratings"].tolist()
operating_temperature = df["Operating Temperature"].tolist()
i_frequency = df["Inductance Frequency - Test"].tolist()
mounting_type = df["Mounting Type"].tolist()
package = df["Package / Case"].tolist()
s_package = df["Supplier Device Package"].tolist()
size_dimension = df["Size / Dimension"].tolist()
height = df["Height - Seated (Max)"].tolist()
unit_price = df["Unit Price,USD"].tolist()
```

I'm trying the web scraping, but I couldn't figure out to how can import the unit price, you can see that at the end of the code, the others work well, but unit price code is not working; I have to figure out on HTML code, how can I describe this? Also, I need a loop for downloading the next multiple pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue of selecting the `unit_price` from the dataframe `df`. You will need to figure out the looping part.

Code:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.digikey.com/products/en/inductors-coils-chokes/fixed-inductors/71/page/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df.columns = [re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", str(i).strip().replace('\n', '')) for i in list((df.columns.get_level_values(0)))]
print(df.columns)

part_numbers = df["Manufacturer Part Number"].values.tolist()
manufacturer = df["Manufacturer"].values.tolist()
quantity_available = df["Quantity Available"].values.tolist()
m_qty = df["Minimum Quantity"].values.tolist()
types = df["Type"].values.tolist()
material = df["Material - Core"].values.tolist()
inductance = df["Inductance"].values.tolist()
tolerance = df["Tolerance"].values.tolist()
current_rating = df["Current Rating"].values.tolist()
current_saturation = df["Current - Saturation"].values.tolist()
shielding = df["Shielding"].values.tolist()
resistances = df["DC Resistance (DCR)"].values.tolist()
freq = df["Q @ Freq"].values.tolist()
frequency = df["Frequency - Self Resonant"].values.tolist()
ratings = df["Ratings"].values.tolist()
operating_temperature = df["Operating Temperature"].values.tolist()
i_frequency = df["Inductance Frequency - Test"].values.tolist()
mounting_type = df["Mounting Type"].values.tolist()
package = df["Package / Case"].values.tolist()
s_package = df["Supplier Device Package"].values.tolist()
size_dimension = df["Size / Dimension"].values.tolist()
height = df["Height - Seated (Max)"].values.tolist()
unit_price = df["Unit Price USD"].values.tolist()

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
Index(['Compare Parts', '', 'Image', 'Digi-Key Part Number',
       'Manufacturer Part Number', 'Manufacturer', 'Description',
       'Quantity Available', 'Unit Price USD', 'Minimum Quantity', 'Packaging',
       'Series', 'Part Status', 'Type', 'Material - Core', 'Inductance',
       'Tolerance', 'Current Rating', 'Current - Saturation', 'Shielding',
       'DC Resistance (DCR)', 'Q @ Freq', 'Frequency - Self Resonant',
       'Ratings', 'Operating Temperature', 'Inductance Frequency - Test',
       'Features', 'Mounting Type', 'Package / Case',
       'Supplier Device Package', 'Size / Dimension', 'Height - Seated (Max)'],
      dtype='object')
   Compare Parts      Image Digi-Key Part Number Manufacturer Part Number  \
0            NaN NaN    NaN        732-1728-2-ND               744765116A   
1            NaN NaN    NaN        732-1728-1-ND               744765116A   
2            NaN NaN    NaN        732-1728-6-ND               744765116A   
3            NaN NaN    NaN       732-10762-2-ND             74404043220A   
4            NaN NaN    NaN       732-10762-1-ND             74404043220A   

             Manufacturer                    Description  \
0  Wurth Electronics Inc.  FIXED IND 16NH 560MA 220 MOHM   
1  Wurth Electronics Inc.  FIXED IND 16NH 560MA 220 MOHM   
2  Wurth Electronics Inc.  FIXED IND 16NH 560MA 220 MOHM   
3  Wurth Electronics Inc.  FIXED IND 22UH 1.11A 200 MOHM   
4  Wurth Electronics Inc.  FIXED IND 22UH 1.11A 200 MOHM   

                      Quantity Available Unit Price USD  \
0  39,000 - Immediate  Available: 39,000       $0.25500   
1  39,942 - Immediate  Available: 39,942       $0.41000   
2  39,942 - Immediate  Available: 39,942     Digi-Reel®   
3  18,000 - Immediate  Available: 18,000       $0.31736   
4  20,170 - Immediate  Available: 20,170       $0.60000   

        Minimum Quantity          ...          Frequency - Self Resonant  \
0  3,000  Minimum: 3,000          ...                             3.1GHz   
1          1  Minimum: 1          ...                             3.1GHz   
2          1  Minimum: 1          ...                             3.1GHz   
3  3,000  Minimum: 3,000          ...                              26MHz   
4          1  Minimum: 1          ...                              26MHz   

  Ratings Operating Temperature Inductance Frequency - Test Features  \
0       -         -40°C ~ 125°C                      250MHz        -   
1       -         -40°C ~ 125°C                      250MHz        -   
2       -         -40°C ~ 125°C                      250MHz        -   
3       -         -40°C ~ 125°C                      100kHz        -   
4       -         -40°C ~ 125°C                      100kHz        -   

   Mounting Type      Package / Case Supplier Device Package  \
0  Surface Mount  0402 (1005 Metric)      0402 (1005 Metric)   
1  Surface Mount  0402 (1005 Metric)      0402 (1005 Metric)   
2  Surface Mount  0402 (1005 Metric)      0402 (1005 Metric)   
3  Surface Mount         Nonstandard                     SMD   
4  Surface Mount         Nonstandard                     SMD   

                        Size / Dimension Height - Seated (Max)  
0  0.039" L x 0.022" W (1.00mm x 0.55mm)       0.024" (0.60mm)  
1  0.039" L x 0.022" W (1.00mm x 0.55mm)       0.024" (0.60mm)  
2  0.039" L x 0.022" W (1.00mm x 0.55mm)       0.024" (0.60mm)  
3  0.157" L x 0.157" W (4.00mm x 4.00mm)       0.098" (2.50mm)  
4  0.157" L x 0.157" W (4.00mm x 4.00mm)       0.098" (2.50mm)  

[5 rows x 32 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ali's answer here's the loop you want:

```
... your initial soup and page parsing ...

while soup.find('a', class_='Next'): # here we search next button on page
    res = requests.get('https://www.digikey.com/' + soup.find('a', class_='Next')['href']) # "clicking on next"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', class_='productTable') # added class of demanded table instead of selecting zero element from list
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

    ...and all your scraping logic goes here...
```